# Setting the font using UIAppearence proxy sets everywhere

Tags: ios, proxy, uilabel, uiappearance

I want to ask a simple question related to setting some attribute using UIAppearence Proxy class in ios application.
Lets say that i am setting the font of UILabel using UIAppearence Proxy class. Now does it sets the font of UILabel everywhere in the app for example if the UITableviewcell has a textLabel property. Does setting the Font or some other property through UIAppearence  also results to set it every where that UIControl exists even inside some other control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the general idea, yes.

To set the properties for specific presentations, you should use the selector `appearanceWhenContainedIn:`, that lets you specify where `UILabels` will be modified.